# Windows 10 not showing the same folders in File Explorer and Internet Explorer file selector

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm seeing some strange behavior on a user's computer. When I try to select a file in an Internet Explorer file selector, I don't see the same folders than I do in Windows.

For example, if I navigate to `C:\Users\username\Documents\`, the subfolders are different.
If I copy a path from the Windows Explorer to the file picker dialog, it shows the right files, but if I go up to `C:\Users\username\Documents\`, it again shows the wrong files.

How does that happen, and how can I solve it?

After some tests this behavior happens only for file upload in Silverlight applications. It happens that the folder displayed there is:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Virtualized\C\Users\username\Documents\
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly. Are you using the File > Open dialog in IE and browsing the Documents folder? Can you post the screenshot of how the dialog looks like, and another screenshot of the folder view.

Comment: @w32sh I speak about the file selector that opens when a web application needs to upload a file. In facts it happens on the computer of a teleworker, so I need to wait for him before I can make screenshots.

Comment: @Burgi : yes, even the folders are different, it's like c:\users\username\Documents points to a different place under internet explorer file selector when using Silverlight.

Comment: Does this behaviour extend to other browsers using the Silverlight plugin?

Comment: @Burgi : no, it works fine with Firefox, and Chrome has disabled Silverlight support.

Comment: @Burgi : It only happens to one user, this user computer is under windows 10. (and many thanks for your help btw).

Comment: I know it is crazy but does the user have multiple local user cache folders? eg: `user.000` or `user.001`?

Comment: @Burgi : No, there's only one "user" folder, but a test went to show me that the displayed folder is C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Virtualized\C\Users\username\Documents\

Comment: It's a **Virtualized Folder**. See [Protecting System Files with UAC Virtualization (Part 1)](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/windows_os_security/Protecting-System-Files-UAC-Virtualization-Part1.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill : yes, the problem vanish if I disable the Protected mode in Internet Explorer, but I'm not sure it's a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, that folder has been *virtualized*. The Silverlight plugin, when attempting to look at it, actually sees a completely different place.

#### First, some history

In the transition from Windows XP to Vista, Microsoft got serious about people running as standard users (as opposed to administrators). Sadly, application developers hadn't gotten serious, and boatloads of programs wrote to "system" locations like `C:\Windows` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. To let those applications continue to run, Microsoft added a feature called *redirection* or *UAC virtualization*. When programs running as standard users tried to write to administrator-only locations, the write succeeded, but the data actually got stored in a per-user location, specifically:

```
\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore
```

#### But what does that have to do with this?

Internet Explorer's Protected Mode causes IE and its plugins to run as something even less powerful than a standard user. The XP → Vista transition introduced the idea of *mandatory levels*. Every securable object has a [mandatory level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb648648(v=vs.85).aspx): low, medium, high, or system. Stuff intended to be written by normal users/programs has a medium mandatory level.

Things that even untrusted programs can write to has a low mandatory level, and that's what Protected Mode IE runs in. Therefore, it can't write on any of your documents or drop bad things in your user folder. The file system is redirected for those plugins to:

```
\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Virtualized
```

Note that mandatory integrity levels can deny access even if the discretionary access control list would otherwise allow it. That can result in some confusion if you're not aware of mandatory access control.

#### How do I check the mandatory level of a file or folder?

Use the `icacls` utility, like `icacls file.txt` or `icacls \path\to\folder`. When I run that on the `Virtualized` folder, I get:

```
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
MYCOMP\Ben:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
Mandatory Label\Low Mandatory Level:(OI)(CI)(NW)
```

As you can see, the folder has a low mandatory level. On my `C:\` drive, I get:

```
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(S,AD)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)
Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level:(OI)(NP)(IO)(NW)
```

The root of my drive has a high mandatory level. Most objects won't show that line; when it's absent, Windows assumes that the object has a medium mandatory level.

#### How do I stop the redirection?

Disabling Protected Mode everywhere would do it, but that would be bad for security. If you trust the site that serves the Silverlight application, you could add it to an Internet zone that has Protected Mode off. Do that by opening the Internet Options dialog, switching to the Security tab, selected the *Trusted sites* zone, and clicking the Sites button.

Comment: Perfect answer, infinitely better than what I could do.